# CODEIGNITER4: how to link value from table_1 to table_2 that I insert using SELECT OPTION tag

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

See I have 2 tables **tbl_office** and **tbl_result**

```
| id | office_name |   | id | office      | rating    | comment |
|----|-------------|   |----|-------------|-----------|---------|
| 1  | Records     |   | 1  | Records     | Satisfied |         |
| 2  | Logistics   |   | 2  | Logistics   | Satisfied |         |
| 3  | HR          |   | 3  | HR          | Neutral   |         |
```

i used a **SELECT OPTION** tag on my form to get the row value of **office_name** from **tbl_office**

**CONTROLLER**

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\SurveyModel;
use App\Models\OfficeMOdel;

class Survey extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        helper(['form','url']);

        $office = new OfficeMOdel();
        $data['office'] = $office->findAll();
       

        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){

            $rules = [
                'office' => ['label' => 'Office', 'rules' => 'required'],
                'rating' => ['label' => 'Rating', 'rules' => 'required']
            ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules)){
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        }else{
            $model = new SurveyModel();

            $newData = [
                'office' => $this->request->getVar('office'),
                'rating' => $this->request->getVar('rating'),
                'comment' => $this->request->getVar('comment'),
            ];

            $model->save($newData);
            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashdata('success','Your Feedback has been successfully added to our system!',);

            return redirect()->to('survey/confirmation');
         }
        }

        echo view ('templates/header_form', $data);
        echo view ('surveyform');
        echo view ('templates/footer_form');
    }
```

**PHP/HTML** for displaying the values of **office_name**

```
<select name="office">

   <?php foreach($office as $row) :?>
   <option><?php echo $row['office_name'] ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

**IT WORKS**, but when I update the value **from office_name** from **tbl_office**, the value on the **tbl_result** does not change. Is there a way to link those value instead of just getting the value of the option when i insert it to the other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store `office` name in your `tbl_result` . Instead this you should to store office_id:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_office` (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(64)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_rating` (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(64)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_result` (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    office_id int,
    rating_id int,
    comment text
);

SELECT `res`.`id`, `o`.`name` AS `office`, `r`.`name` AS `rating`, `comment`
FROM `tbl_result` `res`
JOIN `tbl_office` `o` ON `o`.`id` = `res`.`office_id`
JOIN `tbl_rating` `r` ON `r`.`id` = `res`.`rating_id`
```

[Share SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=886b9059c54608bceb005e4a69e2adcb&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

```
+====+===========+===========+=========+
| id | office    | rating    | comment |
+====+===========+===========+=========+
| 1  | Records   | Satisfied | (null)  |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 2  | Logistics | Satisfied | (null)  |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 3  | HR        | Neutral   | (null)  |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: instead of getting the 'name' from **tbl_office**, i should insert the **id** to the **tbl_result**, so every time the data changes from the table it will get the value **name** from the **id** row right?

Comment: Exactly! Using JOIN you will get actual name

Answer (score 0):

join two table in index

```
  $result = $this->model->select('request_post.*')
            ->join('users', 'request_reply.user_id = users.id', 'left')
            ->join('request_post', 'request_reply.post_id = request_post.id', 'left')
             ->where(['request_post.id'=>['1']])
          
            ->paginate(10, 'default',1, 0);
```